# Error in lattice::latticeParseFormula(x, data = data) : model must be a formula object

Tags: r, rcharts

I tried to use rChart's rNVD3 package's discrete bar plot instead of the same old ggplot2. But it's requiring some formula argument as a first argument. I've not used lattice package and I don't know how to create one.

Here's my data frame:

```
   df <- data.frame(
      Pupil = factor(c("Richy","Shyam","Nithin"), levels=c("Richy","Shyam","Nithin")), 
      Scores = c(75,93,62)
      )
```

Code I used to render the plot:

```
  require(rNVD3)
    bar1 <- nvd3Plot(x = "Pupil", y = "Scores", data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600)
    bar1$printChart("chart1")
```

This is what the error is:

> Error in lattice::latticeParseFormula(x, data = data) : 
>     model must be a formula object

When I tried to rectify the error:

```
 bar1<-nvd3Plot(Scores ~ Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600)
    bar1$printChart("chart1")
```

It just showed the .js code but not the barchart.

```
<div id='chart1' class='nvd3Plot'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        drawchart1()
        function drawchart1(){  
          var opts = {"id":"chart1","yAxis":[],"x":"Pupil","y":"Scores","type":"discreteBarChart","width":600,"height":400},
            data = [{"Pupil":"Richy","Scores":75},{"Pupil":"Shyam","Scores":93},{"Pupil":"Nithin","Scores":62}]

          var data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){
              return opts.group === undefined ? 'main' : d[opts.group]
            })
            .entries(data)

          nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models[opts.type]()
              .x(function(d) { return d[opts.x] })
              .y(function(d) { return d[opts.y] })
              .width(opts.width)
              .height(opts.height)

           d3.select("#" + opts.id)
            .append('svg')
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);

           nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
           return chart;
          });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Try `nvd3Plot(Scores ~ Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600)`. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: I'm not getting even if I run your LOC. Output is not getting rendered. It shows no error too. Instead the above mentioned js code appears. @Pascal

Comment: It is not what I said. If I **really** need to write everything: `bar1 <- nvd3Plot(Scores ~ Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600); bar1$printChart("chart1")`

Comment: That's what I tried for @Pascal It didn't work.

Comment: According to your edit, it is not. I give up. I said `bar1 <- nvd3Plot(Scores ~ Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600); bar1$printChart("chart1")`, not `nvd3Plot(Scores ~ Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600); bar1$printChart("chart1")`

Comment: My extreme apologies @Pascal I didn't include variable only when showing here. But I ran the code with the variable only. No change. Anyways, thanks for your great help. Will handle this issue somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rCharts` can be a little confusing sometimes due to its use of [reference classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html).  You are very close.  First install [`rCharts`.](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts)  Then, instead of `nvd3Plot`, use [`nPlot`](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/R/Nvd3.R#L1-L5) as shown below.  Also, you might be interested in [`htmlwidgets`](http://htmlwidgets.org).

```
library(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(
  Pupil = factor(c("Richy","Shyam","Nithin"), levels=c("Richy","Shyam","Nithin")), 
  Scores = c(75,93,62)
)

# without formula interface
nPlot(
  x = "Pupil", y = "Scores", data = df,
  type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600
)

# with formula interface
nPlot(Scores~Pupil, data = df, type = "discreteBarChart", width = 600)
```